# Why #import NSURL.h OR UIKit/UIKit.h will cause 999+ errors

Tags: objective-c

I need to mix cpp and objective-c in one header file and mm file, (CFacebookInterface.h,CFacebookInterface.mm)

but if I add a BOOL OR NSURL in header file.
I get a error " BOOL" does not name a type AND "NSURL" does not name a type

IF  I  #import  Foundation/NSURL.h    in this header  then  "GET  375 ERROR "

IF  I  #import   Foundation/Foundation.h    then  "COMPILING WILL GET  999+ ERROR "

and all the errors are occured in ios`s framework class like NSZone.h,NSObject.h etc..

Anybody can help ...thanks very much....

```
//#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> //GET  999+ ERROR 
//#import <Foundation/NSURL.h>   //GET  375 ERROR 

#import <SocialInterface.h>



class CFacebookInterface : public SocialInterface 
{
public:
    CFacebookInterface();
    virtual ~CFacebookInterface();

public:
    virtual void        setAppID(CStrWChar key);
    virtual const char* getAttributeName();
    virtual const char* getUserAliasAttributeName();
    virtual void        login();
    virtual void        finishLogin();
    virtual void        logout();
    virtual void        finishLogout();
    virtual void        loadFriends();
    virtual void        finishLoadFriends();
    virtual int32       getConnectionState();
    virtual CStrWChar   getPlayerID();
    virtual CStrWChar   getPlayerAlias();
    virtual int32       getFriendsCount();
    virtual CStrWChar   getFriendIDAtIndex( int index );
    virtual void        postMessage();
    virtual void        postMessage(const CStrWChar & msg);
    virtual void        FinishPostMsg(boolean suc);
    virtual void        resume();

  BOOL              handleOpenURL(NSURL* url);

};

#endif //__FACEBOOKINTERFACE__
```

Comment: Are you including the .h file in any other .cpp file?

Comment: Are you `#include`ing Cocoa or Foundation? Your code snippet shows neither.

Comment: What filetype is the source file you're `#include`ing this header in? For you to import obj-c headers you need to be using a `.mm` file. Also, `#import <NSURL.h>` is naturally going to fail, since the header is `<Foundation/NSURL.h>`.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard  it was mm extension..

Comment: Please paste the first error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your `.cpp` files to `.mm` to have access to both, Objective-C and C++.